# Google Maps API returns a Blank/Empty Screen and Error 400

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I added Google Maps API to Flutter app and it keeps returning a **blank screen** with the **error** `Unexpected response code 400 for https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api`

I added the API to every possible location and I've made dozens of new `API KEYS` and projects, disabled and enabled API's, ran `Flutter Clean` 15 times, read the documentation TWICE, read a couple of Stack Overflow questions and did everything every answer and comment said but **NOTHING**, Can anyone please help.
IOS:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("KEY HERE")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Android:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
             android:value="KEY HERE"/>

//
//
minSdkVersion 20
```

Maps.dart:

```
class Mapp extends StatefulWidget {
  const Mapp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static final kInitialPosition = LatLng(-33.8567844, 151.213108);

  @override
  _MappState createState() => _MappState();
}

class _MappState extends State<Mapp> {
  PickResult? selectedPlace;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Google Map Place Picker"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("Load Google Map"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return PlacePicker(
                          apiKey: "KEY HERE",
                          // APIKeys.apiKey,
                          initialPosition: Mapp.kInitialPosition,
                          useCurrentLocation: true,
                          selectInitialPosition: true,

                          //usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
                          onPlacePicked: (result) {
                            selectedPlace = result;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              selectedPlace == null
                  ? Container()
                  : Text(selectedPlace?.formattedAddress ?? ""),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What tutorial or documentations have you followed?

Comment: I'm guessing that the 400 response code is most likely caused by a billing issue. So do make sure that all is good on that part since 400 response code is a client-side error.

Comment: Thank you @Yrll I have found the solution, it was very simple

Answer (score 0):

I have found the extremely simple solution to this error, the problem was that the `<meta-data` code was not in the right position (I followed a video and in the video he puts it after the `<activity`, but this is incorrect) it should be right after the `<application...>` code

Please feel free to read the docs for more information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation

Comment: Experienced this yesterday when I was working with some flutter project and tried to put the meta-data for the android module. One thing that helped me really is check the console and I believe it mentions there that there's some issue with finding the API key. That helped me deduce that there was something wrong with how I was implementing the metadata.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).